# Node w/ express using ejs: "ReferenceError: plants is not defined"

Tags: node.js, api, express, ejs

I'm getting this error in my when I load my .ejs view:

```
ReferenceError: plants is not defined
```

All of my other views work with the includes and such.

plants.js router:

```
router.get('/plants', plantsController.getPlantsPage);
```

plants.js controller:

```
const Plant = require('../models/plant');

exports.getPlantsPage = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('plants', {
        plants: plants,
        pageTitle: 'Plants',
        path: '/plants',
        hasPlants: plants.length > 0
    });
};
```

plant.js model:

```
module.exports = class Plant {
    constructor(common_name, image_url, scientific_name) {
        this.common_name = common_name;
        this.image_url = image_url;
        this.scientific_name = scientific_name;
    }
}
```

plants.ejs:

```
<% if (hasPlants) { %>
                <% for (let plant of plants) { %>
            <div class="col s12 m4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                          <img class="activator" src="<%= plant.image_url %>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4"><%= plant.common_name %><i class="material-icons right">MORE</i></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-reveal">
                          <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4"><%= plant.common_name %><i class="material-icons right">CLOSE</i></span>
                          <p><%= plant.scientific_name %></p>
                          <p><a href="/plant-details/<%= plant.id %>">Plant Details</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <% } %>
            <% } else { %>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <p>No Plants Added!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% } %>
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you make sure you set the `plants` variable? The error says `plants` is not defined. Try `console.log()` the variable

Comment: Thanks! I feel silly. Solved by adding `const plants = [];` to my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure you set the plants variable? The error says plants is not defined. Try console.log() the variable.